# How to get the value from another table using id with Ajax and Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I was trying Yajra Datatable on Laravel and I found this on the tutorial where I get the values from a single table.
I have to compare the values of each column in the 1st table to the 2nd table like for example the 1st tables status is 1, it would check the status types table which status has the id of 1 and in this example 1 is pending so the datatable would be showing "Pending" instead of number 1
Below here is the code from the Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $documents = Documents::all();
    $status = Status::all();

    return view('document/index', compact('documents', 'status'));
}

public function getDocs(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $docs = Documents::latest()->get();
        return Datatables::of($docs)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $actionBtn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>';
                return $actionBtn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

Here is from the document/index view:

```
$(function () {

    var table = $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('documents.list') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'status', name: 'status'}
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: Why you haven't created a relation between Docs and Status Model ? If you have relation then you can easily access it

Comment: @MAY I'm new to this that's why I didn't know that. I will check that out. Thank you for this comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Define relation between Status and Documents Model

Status Model:

```
public function docs(){
    return $this->hasMany(Documents::class);
}
```

Documents Model:

```
public function state(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Status::class, 'status'); 
    # 'status' is the name of foreign key on documents table
}
```

Documents Controller:

```
public function getDocs(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $docs = Documents::with('state')->select('documents.*')->latest();
        # Here 'documents' is the name of table for Documents Model
        # And 'state' is the name of relation on Document Model.
        return Datatables::of($docs)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('status_str', function($row){
                  # 'name' is the field in table of Status Model
                  return $row->state->name;
             })
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $actionBtn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>';
                return $actionBtn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

Index View:

```
$(function () {

    var table = $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('documents.list') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'status_str', name: 'state.name'}
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: Wow Thank you! This really does works and it's easy to understand. Now I can use this for all the columns that needed to get the names using foreign keys